# Ionic Framework Email Composer - How to choose email app

Tags: ionic-framework

Working on an Ionic Framework app that allows users to send an email. Currently, the app just sends using the device's default email application. Is there any way to allow the user to choose which email app they want to use?

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer/)

According to documentation this plugin takes app as a parameter. Like below;

```
this.email.open({
  app: 'gmail',
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By making following changes in your code, it will open gmail app by default-

For details, refer https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer/

> // add alias
>
> this.emailComposer.addAlias('gmail', 'com.google.android.gm');
>
> // then use alias when sending email
>
> this.emailComposer.open({   app: 'gmail',   ... });